# Return line segment instead of SVG icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have created a SVG icon. But when I click on it. It has chances
that the return object is the line segement of the SVG reather than
the svg element.

Here is the UI:
[image: icon is a SVG]

Here is the evidence:[image: evd]

The clicked target is a POLYGON in the svg...
How can this happen?

Comment: because elements by default accept ``pointer-events``; set it to ``none``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to access the SVG element itself, you need the `Event.currentTarget` property, not `targetElement` or `srcElement`. The [`srcElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement) property is equivalent to the `target` property, but is deprecated. The only [`targetElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimationElement/targetElement) property I can find a reference to is defined on `SVGAnimationElement`s, not on events.

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) (emphasis mine):

> The **`currentTarget`** read-only property of the `Event` interface
> identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses
> the DOM. It always refers to *the element to which the event handler
> has been attached*, as opposed to **`Event.target`**, which identifies *the
> element on which the event occurred and which may be its descendant*.

Take a look at this snippet:

```js
document.querySelector('svg').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log('Target: ' + e.target);
  console.log('Current target: ' + e.currentTarget);
});
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="blue"/>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="35" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this pretty solution! Fast and correct!